# Android - Retrieve file after ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I need my user to upload a file in the app. For that purpose, I used an intent

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "*/*"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, arrayOf("image/*", "application/pdf"))
        }

        startActivityForResult(intent, IMPORT_INTENT_CODE)
```

That intent is working, I can select an image from the phone storage.
However, in the onActivityResult I cannot retrieve the file I selected. When I try to get the file from the URI, I get a nonexisting file.

My final purpose is to get a base64 value for the file but I cannot access the file.

What should I do?